# Trying to install Win 7 from boot and getting "is not recognized as an internal or external command" error

Tags: windows-7

I used Dban to wipe off my HD before selling laptop. But when trying to reinstall windows 7 by booting into USB stick I get the following error:

'c:\multiboot\Windows-7-all-in-one' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
followed by 
x:\Sources>

Please see screenshot: https://photos.app.goo.gl/XYwjboree7FiPZsL8 
I know probably related to fact that 'Windows-7-all-in-one' is not official Microsoft version. 
Is there a way to get past this error?
When I type DIR, i get many files and directories.

Comment: the install script broke, and that was the resulting error message. x:\sources\ is the location of the windows install files. I'd guess that the packaging to get it on the thumbdrive didn't work right.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You were right. Once I redid the  thumbdrive it didn't throw that error. Thank you.